Framer React Scroll animation
How can you help, how to make this scroll card animation, like here: https://thevariable.com/?utm_source=extension&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=muzli
I tried to make it using useScroll framer-motion, but I do not know how to make a card rotate like in reference: https://thevariable.com/?utm_source=extension&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=muzli
I would be grateful if you could help me.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
